# ¿Cómo cambio el valor de una variable?

Tags: javascript

Quiero hacer una página en la cual se te muestre la hora, pasa que al mostrarse la hora, no sale con un cero a la izquierda. Imagino que cambiando algún valor en el new Date() es posible, pero en el ejercicio se me pide que añada un cero a la izquierda a través de un If. He probado ya de todo, principalmente, cambiar el valor de las variables a través de condicionales, pero no me funciona. Quisiera que en el caso de que el valor fuera menor que 10, tanto en los segundos, como en los minutos, como en las horas, aparezca un cero a la izquierda. Os dejo aquí el código, muchas gracias.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Ejercicio 402</title>

    <!--Aquí empieza JavaScript-->
    <script>
        //función para que nos de la hora
        function hora(){
            var areaHora = new Date();

            var horas = areaHora.getHours();

            var minutos = areaHora.getMinutes();

            var segundos = areaHora.getSeconds();

            caja = document.getElementById('tiempo');

            caja.innerHTML = horas+":"+minutos+":"+segundos;

            if (areaHora.getSeconds() < 10) {
                segundos = "0"+areaHora.getSeconds();
        }

        var cronometro = setInterval (hora, 1000);

    </script>
    <!--Aquí acaba JavaScript-->





    <style>
        div#texto {
            font-size: 20px;
            font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
            line-height: 40px;
        }
        div#tiempo {
            position: fixed;
            font-size: 60px;
            top: 25px;
            right: 50px;
            padding: 18px;
            border: 2px solid black;
            background-color:salmon;

        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="texto">

        Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente odio sequi explicabo quo, labore architecto soluta quisquam nesciunt dolorum deserunt reprehenderit totam aspernatur eum, perferendis provident voluptatibus vero ut nobis!

    </div>
    <div id="tiempo">Time</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Y si colocas el `if` antes de `caja.innerHTML`, Tambien en el `if` no utilizes la variable `areaHora` para obtener nuevamente los segundo, mejor utiliza la variable `segundos`. Por cierto te falta cerra la llave del `if`

Comment: Muchas gracias, me has solucionado el problema, de verdad. Aún no entiendo bien el posicionamiento de las cosas, lo he puesto antes de caja.innerHTML y ahora funciona... Sigo sin entender bien como estructurar las cosas en JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que pasa que estas cambiando el valor de la variable pero no la estas volviendo a pintar en tu html

```
     function hora(){
        var areaHora = new Date();

        var horas = areaHora.getHours();

        var minutos = areaHora.getMinutes();

        var segundos = areaHora.getSeconds();
        if (seconds < 10) seconds = "0" + segundos;

        caja = document.getElementById('tiempo');

        caja.innerHTML = horas+":"+minutos+":"+segundos;
    }
```

Con eso deberia funcionar :D!